# Image not filling the UI View

Tags: swift, image, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to create a profile page that has a user image in a UI View. However, when I load the image it does not fill the circular UI View I created.

Here is the code:

```
        profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImageView.anchor(left: view.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: 32, width: 120, height: 120)
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 120 / 2
        profileImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        profileImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

When I fill the profileImageView.image with an image, it turns out like this:

[image]

I want it to fill the whole space. Can anyone help?

Comment: use scaleAspectFill not scaleAspectFit

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `scaleAspectFit` when constructing this image, which will resize the entire image to fit the width OR height you've set. If you want to fill it, I would give `scaleAspectFill` a try. It will likely clip the image on the sides, but it should fill the full space in the way you intend.